# (Kotlin) focus of text field

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, material-design

I have read a number of threads relating to this, but the wide variety of answers makes it a bit confusing for me. I have some Material text fields in 4 different Fragments; what I want is pretty common: when clicking outside the text field (e.g. onto the background), I want both the keyboard to close and the text field to unfocus. Maybe someone can give a clear explanation of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think best solution is make your background focusable, and set focus change listeners on your text fields for control keyboard behavior, like

```
textField.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
                    if (hasFocus) {
                        showKeyboard()
                    } else {
                        hideKeyboard()
                    }
                }
```

Comment: In my MainActivity `onCreate()`, I had tried first making a `val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager` then following your suggestion showing the keyboard with `imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)` and hiding with `imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textField.windowToken, 0)` -- but the app just crashes. I think it has something to do with the InputMethodManager? Do you have any ideas? Maybe there is a simpler approach...

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
class CustomFragment {
...
override fun onViewCreated() {
...
    textField.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            showKeyboard()
        } else {
            hideKeyboard()
        }
    }
}

fun hideKeyboard() {
    requireActivity().hideKeboard(true)
}
...
}

fun FragmentActivity.hideKeyboard(clear: Boolean = false) {
    this.currentFocus?.let { view ->
        (view.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager)
            ?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.windowToken, 0)
        if (clear) view.clearFocus()
    }
}
```

Also you can check view type before clear focus

```
if (view is EditText) ...
```